# Identify plane of symmetry in 3D mesh

Tags: mesh

Is there an efficient way to identify the plane of symmetry in a 3D mesh? Preferably with existing code / software but if anyone knows how to implement it that would also be helpful.

Example of the problem: you have a 3D mesh of a duck that is centered at the origin. The correct answer in this case would be the plane where x = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into this: https://cescg.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k-Estimating-Approximate-Plane-of-Symmetry-of-3D-Triangle-Meshes.pdf
There are definitely other papers on the subject though